# how to present a tabBarViewController(created in storyboard) using code when pressed a particular button in swift5?

Tags: storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, ios13, swift5, xcode11

I have a viewController called as ViewController and I have a button on it , I want to present a tabBarController (which already contains two viewControllers) when pressed a button and I want it fullscreen I have tried a code

```
     let tabbar = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TabBar") as? UITabBarController)       
    tabbar!.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(tabbar!, animated: true)
```

the identifier is actually the storyboard id that I have given to the tabBar Controller on storyboard,
this code actually works but when I press the button that triggers that code it works fine but when I connect the outlets of the viewControllers present on that tabBar Controller on the next build those Viewcontrollers(those on that taBbar) seems to go black and I am not able to see any components that I designed on storyboard And also I get this message in the console

Attempt to present <Sample_App.TabViewController: 0x7f8f5d847200> on <Sample_App.ViewController: 0x7f8f5c607490> (from <Sample_App.ViewController: 0x7f8f5c607490>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
please give me a solution and also a bit of explanation
[here is the snapshot of my story board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hueqb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try put a segue from the ViewController to the TabController

[Set the segue connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtV2A.png)

Now and put an identifier.

[Set the segue ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWqEc.png)

Add a func in your first ViewController and taking the segue identifier to move to the other view.

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueID" {
        let tabBarController = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        tabBarController.title = "TabBarController"
    }
}
```

Then add a button action to call this line

```
@IBAction func infoMessage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueID", sender: nil)
}
```

[This is the implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbESx.png)